# How to use ffmpeg to add jpeg image before and after the video

Tags: windows, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I am using the latest version 2.8.5 ffmpeg on Windows and I want to add 5s intro jpeg frame at the beginning of the video starts, and a 5s jpeg end frame at the end of the video.

I found a lot of example online, but seems all of them are using previous version of ffmpeg, and none of them works with the latest version.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that with the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i intro.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i end.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i video -filter_complex "[2:a]asplit[i][e];[0][i][3:v][3:a][1][e]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

With 1-second fades:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i intro.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i end.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i video -filter_complex "[2:a]asplit[i][e];[0]fade=in:st=0:d=1[0f];[1]fade=out:st=4:d=1[1f];[0f][i][3:v][3:a][1f][e]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

Comment: I have this error: [Parsed_split_0 @ 0000000004f00f20] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_spli
t_0' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_1' filter input pad 1 (a
udio)
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000030f1f60] Cannot create the link split:0 -> concat:1
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Oops. Audio needs `asplit`

Comment: Another user lacked the rep to comment and asked for clarification in a now deleted answer.  They asked where to add the video, and whether you could list the full command.  If you could elaborate, that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 The full command is listed and the placeholder for the video input is also specified. Probably they don't see or realize there's a horizontal scrollbar to see the full string..

Comment: where do I specify input video file name?

Comment: In `-i video` .

Comment: This worked a charm, except I had to add `-vsync vfr` to the beginning for it to work.  Also as has been noted elsewhere, the images must be of identical resolution to the video for it to work.